# How to understand the following quote from termios description

Tags: terminal, process, session

I'm using Mac, following quote is from `man termios`:

> When a controlling terminal becomes associated with a session, its foreground process group is set to the process group of the session leader.

To verify this, I opened a terminal window, ran `sleep` command in the foreground, then opened another terminal windows and ran `ps`:

```
$ ps -o pid,pgid,tpgid,sess,stat,command,tty
  PID  PGID TPGID   SESS STAT COMMAND    TTY
44606 44606 45006      0 S    -bash      ttys000 
45006 45006 45006      0 S+   sleep 3000 ttys000
```

which shows foreground process group as `45006`, to get the session leader I wrote some C code using `getsid` and `getpgid`, then get following info:

```
pid: 45006 pgid: 45006 sid: 44605
pid: 44605 pgid: 44605 sid: 44605
```

the session leader is `44605` which is the login proc:

```
$ ps -o pid,pgid,tpgid,sess,stat,command,tty -p 44605
  PID  PGID TPGID   SESS STAT COMMAND          TTY
44605 44605 45006      0 Ss   login -pfl mz /b ttys000
```

obviously the foreground proc group `45006` differs from session leader proc group `44605`, what am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: the quote doesn't imply the foreground process group won't change, it you exited your shell and checked the login process again you'd notice the tpgid would now equal the session id.

Comment: Hi @don_aman I didn't quite get what you mean, on my mac whenever I open a new terminal window there's a login process and a child shell process like this:
 \-+= 20243 root login -pf mz
   \--= 20244 mz -bash

when I close the terminal window both processes terminate.

Comment: and if you exit the shell how can there be any foreground process

Comment: whoops, my bad. i'm not really a mac user. but i think my point still holds, the foreground process group always changes and it will be the same for all processes sharing a session id/controlling terminal, including the leader.

1. login process creates a session and becomes session leader, at this point tpgid == sess.
2. login forks and execs your shell, which has pid $$. at this point tpgid == $$.
3. shell forks and execs sleep, which has pid $sleep. at this point tpgid == $sleep.
4. sleep exits. at this point tpgid == $$.